сбивается message_id при повторном запуске функции aiogram
создаю бота типа игры и там можно изменять ники через бд, но суть в том что при первом запуске этой функции:
@router.callback_query(F.data == 'rename')
async def rename_user(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(user_states.state_for_name)
    await edit_message(path=r'other_photo//rename.png', caption='Введите новое имя в чат', callback=callback)

@router.message(user_states.state_for_name)
async def end_of_rename_user(message: Message, state: FSMContext, bot: Bot):
    await state.set_state(None)
    await state.set_data({})
    new_user_name = message.text
    bool_new_user_name = main_func_bd('check_name', message.from_user.id, user_name=new_user_name)
    skin = main_func_bd('valid_skin', message.from_user.id)
    if bool_new_user_name:
        main_func_bd('rename', message.from_user.id, user_name=new_user_name)
        text = main_func_bd('profile', message.from_user.id)
        
    elif not bool_new_user_name:
        profile = main_func_bd('profile', message.from_user.id)
        text = f'Такой ник уже существует!\n{profile}'

    await bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id= message.message_id - 1, media=InputMediaPhoto(media=FSInputFile(fr'skins/{skin}.png'), caption=text), reply_markup=profile_markup)
    await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)

ник изменяется, а при повторном запуске выдается ошибка, что сообщение для edit не было найдено:
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: message to edit not found

все остальное работает идеально, кроме этого message_id.
я пытался вычитать из message_id один, типа должно изменяться как раз прошлое сообщение перед тем как пришлется ник игрока, но тогда ошибка возникает при первом запуске функции, получается, что message_id как то стоит на месте вне зависимости присылаются новые сообщения или нет (как раз ник игрока), но это только моя догадка, подскажите, как можно это исправить

Странно, что Вы ожидаете чего-то другого!
После await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id),
как можно успешно await bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=message.chat.id,  message_id= message.message_id, # ...) ?

Дополнение. (после обновления вопроса)
Вот допустим получили ссылки на сообщения из истории:
link_messages_history = (
    'https://t.me/c/1950314177/5/1459',
    'https://t.me/c/1950314177/5/1460',
    'https://t.me/c/1950314177/5/1461',
    'https://t.me/c/1950314177/5/1462'
    )

если удалить сообщение с id == 1461 и заново получить 4 сообщения из истории,
то получим такие ссылки:
other_link_messages_history = (
    'https://t.me/c/1950314177/5/1458',
    'https://t.me/c/1950314177/5/1459',
    'https://t.me/c/1950314177/5/1460',
    'https://t.me/c/1950314177/5/1462'
    )

Вот и думайте, можете ли Вы делать message_id= message.message_id - 1,
или Вам надо сохранять id сообщения которое будете в дальнейшем редактировать в FSM...

удаляется то сообщение, которое присылает пользователь (как раз новый ник), а сообщение, которое присылает бот и которое как раз должно быть редактировано, не удаляется, так как оно отправлялось раньше.

@wanderer В функции and_of_rename_user первый аргумент message! В третьем await Вы удаляете сообщение (message.message_id), а в четвёртом await (этой же функции) пытаетесь его отредактировать message_id= message.message_id - получая id из того же первого аргумента переданного в функцию and_of_rename_user.  Какое "то", какое "которое"? Если код в вопросе фрагментирован, то обновите его так, чтоб он отражал что реально в нём происходит.

код в вопросе изменил, при нажатии на inline кнопку срабатывает функция rename_user, после чего устанавливаетя состояние await state.set_state(user_states.state_for_name). функция edit_message просто изменяет сообщение, не удаляя его. так вот, если я удаляю сообщение, то я могу из message_id этого сообщения вычесть 1, и как раз получиться message_id прошлого сообщения, так ведь? я могу ошибаться, поправьте, если не так (и да я исправил на новый код, который тоже не работает(( )

сделал сохранение message_id как раз через state.update_data. благодарю, что помогли разобраться, думал что это работает иначе
